# C# convert byte* pointer to byte[]?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to do this **without** Copy?

```
int ptrLen = 123;
byte* ptr = ....;

byte[] tmp = ToShallowArray(ptr, ptrLen); //readonly representation of ptr*
```

I don't want to allocate/copy anything, especially arrays which can be various sizes and short-lived.

**Upd**

I know about existance of `Span`/`Memory`/`ArraySegment`/etc and their respective readonly variants. Sad to say this is not an answer, because its not castable to `byte[]` nor puttable into methods which require `byte[]` and their "casting" ususally involves methods such as `ToArray` which is....a **copy**.

Comment: [Span<T>(Void*, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-span-1-ctor\(system-void*-system-int32\))

Comment: Span is not castable to byte[], hence not usable with signatures "Method(byte[] arg)"

Comment: Why do you have a `byte*`? Can you reverse the process to copy data directly into a `byte[]`?

Comment: No, I can't. Not possible.

Comment: Might it be an option to add a `Span<T>` variant to the lib you are using? Is it open source?

Comment: No, not possible. They are either dead or have other priorities than my "feature" requests =)

Answer (score 1):

An array is a specific managed type on the heap where the data is defined as being in the array's payload location, so no you can't create an array that is backed by the original pointer without copying anything.

The good news is that there *is* a concept that does what you want - as noted by @GSerg in the comment: a span is a memory-safe wrapper over any contiguous memory payload, which *could* be an array, but which can also be external memory such as an unmanaged pointer, so:

```
Span<byte> tmp = new(ptr, ptrLen);
```

This has basically the same API as an array, and does everything you would expect, but: there are some rules about where you're allowed to store a span - it can't be a field on a type, for example (except for a `ref struct`), or basically anywhere that might end up stored on the heap (because it needs to track managed references such as interior pointers as well as unmanaged references); this also makes use in `async` methods, local method captures, iterator blocks, and a few other scenarios somewhat tricky.

If you need to *store* the span somewhere (or use it in those restricted scenarios), you can create a `Memory<byte>` (a "memory" is basically a "span provider"). You can see how to do this [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mgravell/Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial/main/src/Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial/UnsafeMemory.cs)

Note that there is also `ReadOnlySpan<T>` and `ReadOnlyMemory<T>` which only provide read semantics (not write semantics), although this is a guideline, not a guarantee (a read-only version can be forced to a writable version trivially).

Comment: How do you put Span<byte> into Method(byte[] arg) ? Its nice concept but unusable most of the time. Also, doesn't present in netstandard nor its variants like ArraySegment/memory/etc

Comment: @eocron It is present in .Net Standard 2.1. If you are using a pre-core .Net, that would be an important thing to mention in the question.

Comment: Updated question. Sorry, its not an easy one question =) Probably set up bounty later.

Comment: @eocron It is an easy question still, it's just that you don't like its answer (which you can see in the first sentence of the answer above).

Comment: @GSerg theoretically, you can copy RawArrayData headers to mock it, preserving a type T[], but I don't know how.

Comment: @eocron You mean like [allocate a `SAFEARRAY` descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11713643/11683), get the runtime to [interpret it as `System.Array`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5885498/11683) and [cast that to `T[]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64896291/11683)?

Comment: @GSerg yeah, same approach as in C++ where you can just manipulate a pointers (well, in C# it will be a bit more than just pointer, including all its header info).

Comment: @eocron you can't treat a span as an array; however, you can treat an array as a span! The answer, then, is to invert things and have a `Method(Span<byte>)` - either in isolation or as an overload (addition). As for netstandard etc: this is available and supported via the System.Memory nuget package (although the version in modern .NET is much more efficient, with runtime changes to optimize it - internally named "fast span" or "two field span" vs the "slow span" or "three field span" in netfx/netstandard). From the caller perspective, it is the same, though.

Comment: I know spans, more than ever for 10 years of exp in C#. If I could use it - I would use it rather than byte[]. Hell, I don't even need byte[] in the first place and can work with non-serializable types, like in C++ (pointers), but C# type-safety is cruel sometimes.

Comment: @eocron what is stopping you using it? If you're talking to an API that you don't control which takes byte[], then the answer is "no, you can't take any shortcuts here". If the external API takes an option offset+count, you could use an array-pool leased buffer to avoid the alloc overhead (you'll still need to pay for the memcopy, though); otherwise, petition to whoever does own that API to support span/memory (which again: is available on all platforms via budget packages, when not inbuilt)

Comment: It's a first one. Old API's.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible, as `byte*` usually refers to unmanaged memory, but a `byte[]` is required to be managed, as an array will always be collected by the *garbage collector*. A `byte*` on the other hand will never be collected by the *garbage collector*, that is the whole point of **unmanaged** memory, you need to manage it yourself. If you could convert the `byte*` directly to a `byte[]` your ability and at the same time responsibility of freeing the memory, would conflict with the task of the garbage collector of guaranteeing memory safety. This would mean, that the garbage collector could no longer guarantee the safety of managed memory and  therefore you **cannot** (and possibly never will be able to) convert an unmanaged `byte*` to a managed `byte[]` without copying it.

Sorry!

Comment: Well, in my case it is all managed. Pointer points to managed memory (particular position in larger byte[] array), but I can't use spans unfortunatelly. Larger byte array is changing but its lifetime is singleton, so it dies with app, so I can ignore GC problems completely.

Comment: Your pointer may point to managed memory, but it does not necessarily have to and because there is no way to guarantee that it actually points to managed memory. You may know that, but the runtime surely does not know that.  Also if you have a managed pointer, you should put it inside a fixed statement to prevent it being moved by the garbage collector.

Comment: Well, thats sad =( I guess it is main reason Span/Memory was created in the first place, cause there is no other way to make pointer which casts to byte[] (length checking, type checking, etc)